# find string with most occurrences in .txt file with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, count, scripting

I'm currently working on a school assignment in powershell and I have to display the word longer then 6 characters with the most occurences from a txt file. I tried this code but it's returning the number of occurrences for each word and it's not what i need to do. Please help.

```
$a= Get-Content -Path .\germinal_split.txt
foreach($object in $a) 
{
if($object.length -gt 6){
$object| group-object | sort-object -Property "Count" -Descending | ft -Property ("Name", "Count");
}
 }
```

Comment: If you are going to use `group-object`, then you don’t need to iterate your list. Just use `$a | group-object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
$a = Get-Content -Path .\germinal_split.txt
$a | Where Length -gt 6 | Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

**Explanation:**

`Where` specifies the `Length` property's condition. `Group-Object -NoElement` leaves off the `Group` property, which contains the actual object data. `Sort-Object` sorts the grouped output in ascending order by default. Here the `Count` property is specified as the sorted property and the `-Descending` parameter reverses the default sort order.

Answer (score 1):

From the question we don't know what's in the text file.  The approaches so far will only work if there's only 1 word per line.  I think something like below will work regardless:

```
$Content = (Get-Content 'C:\temp\test12-01-19' -raw) -Split "\b"

$content | 
Where-Object{$_.Length -ge 6} |
Group-Object -Property Length -NoElement | Sort-Object count | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Here I'm reading in the file as a single string using the -Raw parameter.  Then I'm splitting on word boundaries.  Still use Where to filter out words shorter than 6 characters.  Now use Group-Object against the length property as seen in the other examples.

I don't use the word boundary RegEx very often.  My concern is it might be weird around punctuation, but my tests look pretty good.

Let me know what you think.